# What's the matter with this "Unicoin" advertisement?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign

Today I found this strange Unicoins advertisement at my side bar on PSE, which puzzled me a bit. Seems there is someone trying to lure people into paying real money for a couple of "optical enhancements" for this site. For me, it looks like a new form of spam. Is this officially approved by the stack exchange network?

Comment: Check your date.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau: got me :-)))

Comment: Just FYI, if you tried paying, regardless of payment method (credit, reputation, bitcoin, etc), it would say that a technical error prevented it from accepting X type of payments.

Comment: @Bobson: surprise, surprise :-)))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Stack Exchange Inc. does not endorse or encourage behaviors that should not be endorsed or encouraged. Not legal tender except in localities with citizenship rights for unicorns.

I think they've done a good job of full disclosure and we should allow stack exchange to be a magic pasture *all* uni*s can play in.